# How can I debug this? AttributeError: 'StdoutLogger' object has no attribute 'buffer'

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

My scrapy code gets this error on Scraping Hub, but not locally. AFAICT I'm using Python 3.8 and Scrapy 2.1.0 in both places.

Anybody know what's going on here? I can't find the source to `StdoutLogger` to try figuring it out.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 68, in __init__
    _stdout = sys.stdout.buffer
```

Comment: When you deployed to ScrapingHub... did you make sure to pick the actual 3.x image... it defaults to 2.7 unless told otherwise...eg: have you checked you've done what's in https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200387-deploying-python-3-spiders-to-scrapy-cloud

Comment: Thanks @JonClements I'm using the 2.1 scrapy package which _looks_ to be Python 3, although the name isn't marked -py3. I'll trying another stack.

Comment: Does the issue happen with 2.0?

Comment: Hmm, the failing line has been there for a while when Scrapy runs with Python 3.

Comment: Is your code altering or wrapping `sys.stdout` in any way? Any idea where that `StdoutLogger` class comes from?